# How to split received raw packets from host to several dockers according VLAN using DPDK?

Tags: docker, networking, packet-sniffers, dpdk, vlan

How to split received raw packets from host to several dockers according VLAN using DPDK?

Have an DPDK NIC and raw traffic income from different VLANs. I want to split traffic to several docker containers according VLAN tag. Trying OVS and virtio_user seems to much overhead. Seems I need some l2fwd app with fastest forward way to docker without any routing/processing.